# How can I put data attributes within an Ajax.BeginForm?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

Because I am using Knockout in my view, I have set my form tag accordingly;

```
<form class="employeeListEditor" data-bind="submit: save">
```

However when I click the submit button, I want to do a partial page refresh. So how do I set the data-bind attribute in the Ajax.BeginForm?

This syntax does not work;

```
<% using (Ajax.BeginForm("GetCalendar", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "siteRows" }, new { data-bind="submit: save", class="employeeListEditor" }))
{%>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to use unserscore (`_`)  in your attribute name and the `Ajax.BeginForm` helper (in fact all the HTML helpers replaces unserscore with dashes in the given htmlAttributes object parameters)  will be automatically replace it with a dash (`-`)

```
new { data_bind="submit: save", @class="employeeListEditor" }
```

And you need use an `Ajax.BeginForm` [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492974(v=vs.100).aspx) which accepts htmlAttributes like [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492974(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
<% using (Ajax.BeginForm(
          "GetCalendar", // actionName
          null, // routeValues
          new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "siteRows" }, // ajaxOptions
          new { data_bind="submit: save", @class="employeeListEditor" } // htmlAttributes
         ))
{%>
```

Comment: Thank you. The null has to be there for the route values for this to work.